# Save Android camera focus and white balancing state

Tags: android, camera, focus

To completely understand my problem, one needs to know the exact flow of the app. I have briefly explained it here:

Activity1:
    State = 0:
        On button click, autofocus is called on the camera and a picture is taken, state incremented to 1 and preview started again for capturing the second photo.
    State = 1:
        On button click, second picture is taken(without calling the autofocus again i.e using the old state of the camera, to make sure that the focus state for both the images is same. State is incremented, CAMERA is RELEASED at this point, and activity2 is started.

Activity2:
    State = 2:
        If the user is happy with both the images, he taps on the images and the flow moves on, if he presses back button at this stage, he is taken BACK to Activity1 where he can capture the second picture(or both pictures again).
    When he is redirected back to the Activity1, if he chooses to take both the pictures again, there is no issue because the camera focuses again for taking the first picture and then he can take the second picture with the same camera settings. Now the problem arises when the user wants to only retake the second picture, what happens is the camera doesn't focus here and the picture is blurry, at a later stage both these images are merged and if both these images dont have the same focus/white balance, it is clearly visible in the merged photo.

Is there any way I can save the state the camera is in when the activity is closed so that I can reuse it later and when the user comes back?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to not release the Camera.
You can check the function `void setAutoExposureLock(boolean toggle)` but it will lock the exposure only for the lifetime of Camera.

Comment: yeah I figured, but I want to keep both the activities separate.